# Rerun only the failed stages in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a declarative pipeline, where each stage has several parallel stages. After triggering the pipeline, it looks something like this,
[image]

Now, what I want is, after the build is completed, if any of the stage, running parallel, gets failed, I will rerun those failed stages only. Not the whole suite. For instance, in "Meta Data Creation" stage, if 'Activity Category Type' and 'Campaign' stage get failed, I will rerun only those two stages. I don't want to rerun the other parallel stages inside of the Meta Data Creation, that are passed.
I've tried "Restart from stage" option in Jenkins UI. But, it won't run the specific failed stages only. I've also tried Retry{} block. But, it halts the pipeline, when an error occurs. And the pipeline won't go forward until that specific stage is fixed.

So, is there a workaround, where I can revisit the pipeline after it's completed and rerun only the failed stages? [No successful stages will be run]

I've read several other questions here, but none of them had a relevant answer.
Thanks in advance.